# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined for axios wrapper

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a bit of a similar issue [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288816/cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined-with-axios-and-react-in-actions) but I can't seem to get it right. I know I have to `return` a promise and I think I do, although it's still not accepted. Here is my wrapper function for axios calls:

```js
export const callGraph = (url, token) => {
  return axios.get(url, {headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }})
}
```

This is the function that invokes `callGraph` that in turn should return a `Promise`:

```js
export const getGraphProfile = () => {
  if (auth.getAccount()) {
    auth.getToken(loginRequest)
      .then(response => {
        return callGraph(graphConfig.graphMeUrl, response.accessToken)
      })
      .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
  }
}
```

As you can see I explicitly request `return callGraph` so I can use it like this:

```js
getGraphProfile()
   .then(response => { console.log('givenName ', response.data.givenName) })
   .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

For one reason or another I'm still missing something. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are not returning anything from the outer function (`getGraphProfile`). Return the result of the `auth.getToken` call. In the case that `auth.getAccount` returns false, note that you will return `undefined`, and you will break the caller. You can return a rejected promise to cover that case. But I think it would be cleaner to use async / await.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use a `rejected` promise?  Would that just be `new Promise((reject) => {reject('my error')})` in the `.catch` part?

Comment: to create a rejected promise you can use the helper: `Promise.reject('reason')`. But I would like to ask, what's the expected behavior of the `getGraphProfile` function when `auth.getAccount()` returns false? Should it "error"? Should it return some "default* value ?

Comment: It should return the error coming from `auth.getToken()`. Then the caller who calls `getGraphProfile` can still decide what to do in the catch clause. Thx for that oneliner, very convenient.

Comment: If `auth.getAccount` returns false, `auth.getToken` is not invoked since it won't enter the if. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is correct, my mistake. I need to redesign this so it's coherent. Sorry, I'm still learning as I just started with javaScript. But thank you for letting me know what the flaw was.

Comment: Don't worry! Ask any questions you have. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the axios promise

```
export const getGraphProfile = () => {
  if (auth.getAccount()) {
    return auth.getToken(loginRequest)
      .then(response => {
        return callGraph(graphConfig.graphMeUrl, response.accessToken)
      })
      .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought I did that with adding `return` before `callGraph`. But apparently it needs to be returned again by the parent function as you stated. Thank you very much, I've been staring at this one for a while now. Appreciate it :)

Comment: i know that feeling, sometimes the mistake is infront of you but you dont see it